# React native webview copy and download not working

Tags: android, react-native, clipboard, android-download-manager, react-native-webview

I have built an android app using react native. Inside the app I am using the
`react-native-webview` package to show a React app.

```
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

<WebView
  useWebKit={true}
  source={{
    uri: 'https://myappurl.com',
  }}
  style={{flex: 1}}
/>
```

I have set the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in andoid manifest and also set `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in gradle properties. Yet when I copy something in the react app or download a file, it doesn't happend at the device level. If I run the react app independently in a web browser I am able to copy and download.

According to the documentation of `react-native-webview` nothing else needs to be done and this functionality should be inbuilt. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still stumbles upon this answer: I've found this [Github answer](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2480#issuecomment-1493347030) that perfectly solves the problem (even using `navigator.clipboard.writeText(...)`) by pushing a message in JS on the website's side and then catching it in the React Native code to then use the `Clipboard` community module to copy the text.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue. For copy i was using the `navigator.clipboard` api and for download i was using a blob object. The web view only supports the `document.execCommand()` api for copy, and for download it only supports download through the `Content-Disposition: attachment;` header.